# Mobile internal storage type

Tags: android, storage

Does anyone know what type the internal flash storage is in mobile devices?

I would like to know about the nexus 4,5,7,9.
I have tried some specs but I did not find anywhere to specify the type (NAND, NOR eMMC,....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nexus uses Raw Nand flash for internal storage. For Bootloader, Rfs, kernel and preinstalled applications. 
you can find more information on this in the paper "Revisiting Storage for Smartphones" by NEC Laboratories America

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look.